# Google's Text To Speech available Voices (portuguese)

Tags: android, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I've implemented TTS and successfully implemented it with the language I'm interested in. My question now is if I could get any more variety of Voices in the same language. I'm only getting a standard female voice. (even when I add "male" as a feature to the Voice)

When I print the tts.getVoices() method I get that only one voice is available. However, if I visit [this website](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/voices) I see that google has 4 standard pt-PT voices, plus 4 WaveNet pt-PT additional ones.

Does anyone know how is it possible to integrate any of these 8 voices into my app? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tts.getVoices() is a method provided by the Android TextToSpeech class.

It returns the list of voices that are available to *the particular TTS engine that happens to be installed on the device you are testing with*.  The results of tts.getVoices() will differ by device and depend on:

1) The type of engine (Google, Samsung, PICO, etc.) the user/manufacturer has installed.

2) How up-to-date the installed version of that engine is.

The website you reference is *Google Cloud text-to-speech* which is different than the Android TextToSpeech class.

The Google Cloud service works independently of any device framework -- in an Android app (or any app on any platform), you would simply make a normal http request to the Google cloud server and you would be returned an audio file.

Documentation: https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/apis.